# How to change the background in the table?

Tags: rwd-theme

How to change the background color in the table? Template RWD Magento.[image: photo]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general CSS based question, and more suitable for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `.toolbar{background:'your color'};` to style.css inside skin folder and to change the inner font color use `.sort-by option {
  color: red !important;
}`

Comment: [link rwd theme](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/women/pants-denim.html) I need to change the color in the box.

Comment: answer edited  please check

Answer (score 0):

Post this kind of questions on Stack Overflow with a CSS tag, it has nothing to do with Magento and it's already answered on Stack Overflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/622945